# How to set Stale time for OkHttp Android?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am creating an android app which fetched all of its data from a webservice.
And i am using Okhttp as a networking layer. I am able to set the cache size of okhttp but i want to set the stale time after which okhttp fetches data from server otherwise fetched it from local cache.

Whenever i press back and exit the app. After relaunching, it again goes to get the data from server. Is it possible to get the data from local cache for stale time like 15 minutes ? And after 15 minutes is over and user launches the app again then data comes from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `Cache-Control: max-age= 900` in the response of your request. This way you are telling `OkHttp` to cache that response for 15 minutes (900 seconds).

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching).

If you want to do it programmatically on the device end, you can **re-write** response using interceptors. Use it like this:

```
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
@Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
       .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=900")
       .build();
     }
};
```

Add this to your `OkHttp` client while building it:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
   .addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
   .build();
```

You are good to go!

Comment: How to do it programatically ? Is there any method available in com.squareup.okhttp.Response class to do it or is there any other way ?

Comment: Thanks for the information but the problem is i am using OkHttp 2.7.0 and i am not able to find a way to add interceptors to it.

Comment: You can use it. [OkHttp's interceptors require OkHttp 2.2 or better.](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#availability)

Comment: But there is no OkHttpClient.Builder() available ?

Comment: try to use it like this: `client.networkInterceptors().add(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);` Where `client` is `OkHttp` client. [ref](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-260)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108965/discussion-between-passiondroid-and-rohit-arya).